# How to use checkout.onepage.billing.extra

Tags: onepage-checkout, magento-1

I want to include some text in `Billing Information` section of the one page checkout. There's a call in `base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml` like this:

```
<?php /* Extensions placeholder */ ?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout.onepage.billing.extra')?>
```

Is the correct way to use this reference in an extension something like this:

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
            <block type="core/template" name="my.billing.bit" as="checkout.onepage.billing.extra" template="my/extension/checkout/onepage/billing.extra.phtml" />
        </reference>
 </checkout_onepage_index>
```

I can't seem to get it to work another way, but **it seems wrong that I replace the whole block, what if another extensions wants to**?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is really disturbing.

I reckon another solution would be to use a `core/text_list` block that will automatically render all its children.

```
<checkout_onepage_index>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
            <block type="core/text_list" name="checkout.onepage.billing.extra" as="checkout.onepage.billing.extra">
                <block type="core/template" name="my.billing.bit" template="my/extension/checkout/onepage/billing.extra.phtml" />
            </block>
        </reference>
 </checkout_onepage_index>
```

Thus every other modules can reference `checkout.onepage.billing.extra` directly to add their block and it will automatically be rendered.